# How to add double quotes in a string literal

Tags: vb6, double-quotes

Example code:

```
Dim a As String
a = 1234,5678,9123
```

I want to add literal double quotes to the variable `a`

Expected Output:

```
a = "1234,5678,9123"
```

How do I format the string so when I print it, it has double quotes around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape double quote in VB string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835691/escape-double-quote-in-vb-string)

Comment: IS this just in the VB sources? Or is there something more here? The obvious question is why can't you just type this? Can you provide more context -- is this code that you need to refactor? How many instances are we talking about here as well? Are all variables declared as "Dim a as string"? What other constraints are there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape double quote in VB string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835691/escape-double-quote-in-vb-string)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to include `"` in a string, supply `""` where you want the quote to appear. So your example should read...

```
a = """1234,5678,9123"""
```

Answer (score 18):

The current answers are correct and valid but sometimes the following can improve readability:

```
a = Chr$(34) & "1234,5678,9123" & Chr$(34)
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but that is NOT more readable! Are all developers expected to know the entire ASCII character code set? Create a constant and assign it that value; then, simply use the constant

Comment: Well I only said *can* - just to give another option to the OP. And I didn't say this was best practise. You can find the ASCII character set [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) - then you don't have to remember it.

Comment: +1 I see Chr(34) all over the place, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: This is far easier to read because you don't have to make sure you are doubling up each quote. Plus the string is there in plain English.

Comment: A few years later this still helps! + 1

Comment: `Chr$()` is also a function call so will be slower than a string literal or a constant.

Comment: @Deanna - valid point but I suspect the difference would be negligible.

Comment: create a global constant:
    Public Const vbDoubleQuote As String = """" 'represents 1 double quote (")

and use it like: a = vbDoubleQuote & "blabla" & vbDoubleQuote

Answer (score 11):

To make Chr$(34) more readable:

```
Dim quote as string
quote = Chr$(34)
a = quote & "1234,5678,9123" & quote
```

This makes it easier to get the correct number of " symbols everywhere and is readable.

Answer (score 8):

```
a = """1234,5678,9123"""
```

or

```
a= """" & a & """"
```

Comment: @MattWilko It does if `a` is typed as a string as per the OP. If however they use a numeric variable or literal in there, the `+` should be `&`, or the value passed to `CStr()`.

Comment: @MattWilko Sorry :) I've updated the answer to use `&` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You just use `Chr$(34)` to insert a double quotes.

Eg:

Dim i as String

```
i = Chr$(34) & "Hello World" & Chr$(34) 'Shows "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add any kind of complicated functions just use following example to insert double in text box or rich text box.

```
Dim dquot=""""
TextBox1.AppendText("Hello " &dquot &"How are you ?" &quot)
```

or

```
Dim dquot=""""
RichTextBox1.AppendText("Hello " &dquot &"How are you ?" &quot)
```

Answer (score -2):

I used the Chr$(34) method, like this:

```
Sub RunPython()
    Dim scriptName As String
    Dim stAppName As String
    scriptName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\aprPlotter.py"
    stAppName = "python.exe " & Chr$(34) & scriptName & Chr$(34)
    Debug.Print stAppName
    Call Shell(stAppName, vbHide)
End Sub
```

I was using the same path for the python script as the Excel Workbook, to keep it easier for the users. I monkeyed with the quotes for 45 minutes before I found this thread.  When the paths are sourced from active working locations (especially ones with spaces in Windows), I think this is a preferred method.  Hopefully, this will help someone else.