# How to add quotation marks to 2 strings and variable in the middle

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add quotations to a piece of string that is broken in 2 pieces with a variable in the middle.

I have tried many, many ways...many ways and failed.

Example:

Dim path as String = "C:\Users\" & CurrentUser & "\folder\path to something\"

I need the whole result to be in quotations to pass it to a command that requires the path with spaces in quotations.

"C:\Users\Nemo\Folder\Path to something\"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To combine parts of a path, it is usually best to use the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) method. To add a double-quote, use `""""`. So, `Dim path as String = """" & Path.Combine("C:\Users\", CurrentUser, "\folder\path to something\") & """"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add double quotes in a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574682/how-to-add-double-quotes-in-a-string-literal)

Comment: `ChrW(34) & TheString & ChrW(34)`

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use `""` inside the string assignment that you have.  So with your example it would look like this:

```
Dim path As String = """C:\Users\" & CurrentUser & "\folder\path to something\"""
```

Comment: Never mind.  Now I see how the editing works.  I had no idea I was editing someone else's answer.  I thought my answer was changed somehow.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is a good idea to use CHR(34) instead of actual quotes when concatenating strings.  Your code should look like this:

```
Dim current user as string="Nemo"
Dim path as String = CHR(34) & "C:\Users\" & CurrentUser & "\folder\path to something\" & CHR(34)
```

The result will be:
"C:\Users\Nemo\folder\path to something\"