# Excel VBA FSO.GetFolder(folderPath) working in 2007 but not 2010

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm pretty new to VBA.

The below code works fine in 2007 for listing all of the `PDF files` in a particular folder.  However, this code doesn't seem to work when I try it in excel 2010 (it throws an error on `Set fold = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)`)

Any Ideas What I'm doing wrong?

I do have Scripting Runtime checked. My code is below:

```
Sub List_files()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim fold As Folder
Dim f As File
Dim folderPath As String
Dim i As Integer

folderPath = "S:\Academic Affairs\Academic Operations Reporting\CV's"
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set fold = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)

i = 2
For Each f In fold.Files
    If LCase(Right(f.Name, 3)) = "pdf" Then
        Range("A" & i).Value = f.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Did you add the proper references ?

Comment: I ran your code on my machine with XL 2010 worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a "\" on the folderPath variable... so that it is

folderPath = "S:\Academic Affairs\Academic Operations Reporting\CV's\"

If that doesn't fix it, post the error you're getting.

Comment: I added the \ and it didn't fix it.  Run time error 76, file path not found.  I've checked the name a dozen times.  There's about a dozen users using this program in excel 2007 and they're not receiving the error, but I do on 2010

Comment: Sorry guys, I figured it out.  I don't know why but it appears that the name of my S:\ drive is "Academic Affairs" and in 2010 it doesn't let me express it this way: "S:\Academic Affairs\Academic Operations Reporting\CV's" but now works when I express it this way: ""S:\Academic Operations Reporting\CV's.  However, 2007 works just fine with the original method.

Comment: If you have spaces in file/folder names it's often necessary to escape them with an extra set of quotes. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835691/escape-double-quote-in-vb-string 
I prefer to use underscores _ instead of spaces as it's more robust

Comment: Original spelling of your path works in 2016. Also note that apostrophes are interpreted as comments in VBA

Answer (score 2):

Here is a procedure that I use for listing files:

```
Function GetFileList(pDirPath As String) As Variant
On Error GoTo GetFileList_err

    ' Local constants / variables
    Const cProcName = "GetFileList"
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim c As Double           ' upper bound for file name array
    Dim i As Double           ' iterator for file name array
    Dim vFileList() As String ' array for file names

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(pDirPath)
    c = objFolder.Files.Count
    i = 0

    ReDim vFileList(1 To c)  ' set bounds on file array now we know count

    'Loop through the Files collection
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'Debug.Print objFile.Name
        i = i + 1
        vFileList(i) = objFile.Name
    Next

    'Clean up!
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    GetFileList = vFileList

GetFileList_exit:
    Exit Function

GetFileList_err:
    Debug.Print "Error in ", cProcName, " Err no: ", Err.Number, vbCrLf, "Err Description: ", Err.Description
    Resume Next

End Function

Sub PrintFileList(pDirPath As String, _
                  Optional pPrintToSheet = False, _
                  Optional pStartCellAddr = "$A$1", _
                  Optional pCheckCondition = False, _
                  Optional pFileNameContains)
On Error GoTo PrintFileList_err

    ' Local constants / variables
    Const cProcName = "PrintFileList"
    Dim vFileList() As String ' array for file names
    Dim i As Integer          ' iterator for file name array
    Dim j As Integer          ' match counter
    Dim c As String

    vFileList = GetFileList(pDirPath)
    c = pStartCellAddr
    j = 0

    For i = LBound(vFileList) To UBound(vFileList)
        If pPrintToSheet Then
            If pCheckCondition Then
                ' if pFileNameContains not in filename go to next iteration of loop
                If InStr(1, vFileList(i), pFileNameContains, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    GoTo EndLoop
                End If
            End If
            Range(c).Offset(j, 0).Value = vFileList(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
        'Debug.Print vFileList(i)
        i = i + 1
EndLoop:
    Next

PrintFileList_exit:
    Exit Sub

PrintFileList_err:
    Debug.Print "Error in ", cProcName, vbCrLf, "Err no: ", Err.Number, _
                vbCrLf, "Err Description: ", Err.Description
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

The function is just for internal use, you call the procedure. Here is an example call (in this case using the userprofile windows environment variable as the path rather than a hard coded path):

```
call PrintFileList(environ("userprofile"), True, "$A$1", True, ".pdf")
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever things are not working as they "should" it's very productive to start with a minimal approach that works and build from there.
Try this that works in Excel 2016:

```
Option Explicit

Sub File_renaming2()
    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim mySource As Folder
    Dim myFolder As File

    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = objFSO.GetFolder("S:\Academic Affairs\Academic Operations Reporting\CV's\")
    For Each myFolder In mySource.Files
        Debug.Print myFolder.Name
    Next myFolder
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to explain:
But we need to make the full reference to the object type

```
CHANGE                            
    "Dim mySource As Folder "         
TO
    "Dim mySource As Scripting.Folder"    'OR "Dim mySource As object"
```

Why ?
In my case the working code stopt from working
=> I added the "microsoft outlook object library" => it has a "Folder" type to
=> so nothing worked for me aftherwards