# Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected - Registry Error

Tags: windows, vb.net, registry

I am creating a start-up 2nd level logon screen for businesses and corporate companies to use. However, I am trying to disable using Task Manager by using a Registry DWORD Value. When I add in the code, it comes up with the error "Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected". What can I do?

```
    Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1
    Dim regKey As RegistryKey
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("regKey.SetValue("***HKEY***\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System")
        regKey.SetValue("DisableTskMgr", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)

    End Sub
    Private Sub frmMyform_FormClosing(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Dim Cancel As Boolean = eventArgs.Cancel
        Dim UnloadMode As System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason = eventArgs.CloseReason
        If UnloadMode = CloseReason.UserClosing Then

            Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

My problem is with the HKEY system above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is that your actual code or were you trying to highlight where the error is (use a comment line for that).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should look like this:

```
regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey( "regKey.SetValue(""***HKEY***\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"")" )
```

See [Escape double quote in VB string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835691/escape-double-quote-in-vb-string)

```
MsgBox("""") ' Prints a single "
```