# How do I insert only 1 double quotation mark in a string

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a string that only contains 1 double quotation mark. Every time I try to type insert only 1 quotation mark it adds another as a pair. Here's an example of what I want and what I get instead:

This is what I want:

```
textbox.Text = """  'I only want 1 double quotation mark like so
```

This is what I get instead:

```
textbox.Text = """"  'Visual studio adds in another quote, making it 2 instead of 1
```

How would I get visual studio to only insert 1 double quote rather than 2?

Comment: [Four consecutive " characters is how you create a string with 1 double quotation mark](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983682(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I downvoted you because it took about 5 seconds to search for this on google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835691/escape-double-quote-in-vb-string

Comment: In my opinion, what would deserve a downvote would be a question that is irrelevant or just pointless. My ignorance is one thing but a simple gesture in the right path would have been a more mature and appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

im not a .net developer but i believe every programming language has this what we called scape sequence. in java we can do it like this

String str = "\"dude google first\".";

Answer (score 0):

The double quotation is just escape that is used within a string to indicate a single quotation