# How to escape a quotation mark in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

so basically I'm trying to escape a quotation mark in VB.

I have the following code:

```
RichTextBox2.Text = "<furnitype id=" + TextBox3.Text + "
```

And I need:

```
RichTextBox2.Text = "<furnitype id="" + TextBox3.Text + ""
```

So basically the text that is within the textbox3 needs to be quoted, but I can't do so since it requires quotation to add text.

Comment: Posible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835691/escape-double-quote-in-vb-string

Comment: @DiegoS I'm not using console.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you're using the Console or not.  A string is a string.

Comment: It doesn't work when I use double quotation.

Comment: VB.Net <> basic <> vba <> vbscript <> VB6. Please use only the tags that are actually relevant to your question, instead of just randomly adding those that sound familiar. A *car* is not like a *cat* just because they both start with *ca*. Tags have meaning and relevance here. If you're not sure a tag applies, don't use it; if it's necessary, someone here will add it for you. (And if it *needs quotation but you can't do so since it requires quotation*, just add more quotes on each side. In other words, quote the quotes you need.)

Comment: Also, in VB, use & rather than + to concatenate strings ;)

Answer (score 7):

You escape a double quote with another double quote, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("He said ""Hello"" to me.")
```

will display:

> He said "Hello" to me.

In your case, I think you code should be something like this:

```
RichTextBox2.Text = "<furnitype id=""" & TextBox3.Text & """>"
```

I would tend to suggest using `String.Format` or string interpolation to make the code clearer though:

```
RichTextBox2.Text = String.Format("<furnitype id=""{0}"">", TextBox3.Text)
```

or:

```
RichTextBox2.Text = $"<furnitype id=""{TextBox3.Text}"">"
```

Note that string interpolation is only available in VB 2015 or later.

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  We can't know what you did wrong if we don't know what you did.

Comment: So, can we assume that it DOES work when you do it right?  In future, NEVER just say "it doesn't work" because 9 times out of 10 at a minimum it's the implementation that is wrong, not the principle.  If you don't show us what you did then you're wasting our time, whether it's intentional or not.  The code that doesn't do what you want is ALWAYS relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Escape Double Quote with an additional double quote. To solve your particular string for you:

```
RichTextBox2.Text = "<furnitype id=""" + RichTextBox2.Text + """"
```

Comment: For your information, you probably got a downvote on this answer because you did not give an explanation.

Comment: Also, in VB, use & rather than + to concatenate strings ;)