# Send a list of items with hyperlink attached ASP.net VB

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to send an email with a list of items. This items has a link attached in a grid view.

```
Dim mm As New MailMessage()
       mm.To.Add(txtEmail.Text)
       mm.From = New MailAddress("librarieonlineASE@gmail.com")
       mm.Subject = "Comanda dvs. a fost plasata"

       mm.Body = "Comanda dvs se poate descărca de la aceste adrese: <ul>"

       For Each row As DataRow In shoppingCart.Rows
           mm.Body += "<li>"
           mm.Body += row(1) + " " + "<a href="row(8)"></a>"
           mm.Body += "</li>"
       Next
```

I am getting the error end "End of statement expected" at this line 
mm.Body += row(1) + " " + ""

Row 1 has the name of the item and Row 8 has the link which I want to attach. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape a quotation mark in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310095/how-to-escape-a-quotation-mark-in-visual-basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the quotes (`""`). You need to escape the `""` when using to define your hyperlink reference.

The correct way to escape `""` in VB.net is to double them like

```
<a href=""abc""></a>"
```

Also the way you use row(8) will mean that the link will not get the value from the array. 
Use string.Format -

```
Dim link As String
link = String.Format("<a href=""{0}""</a>", row(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your logic to combine string values

```
For Each row As DataRow In shoppingCart.Rows
           mm.Body &= "<li>"
           mm.Body &= row(1) & " " & "<a href="row(8)"></a>"
           mm.Body &= "</li>"
       Next
```

In vb.net we should combine string values using & instead of +

Hope this help.