# BASIC - How to include double quotes in string?

Tags: basic, plc

I'm using the BASIC language. Is there any way to include double quotes in a string?

I tried using `\"` but it doesn't work.

**NOTE:** I'm using [Nano-10 PLC](http://www.triplc.com/nano10.htm) which supports combination of Ladder and BASIC

Comment: You can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4841206/6055311

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[vlad awtsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7397958/vlad-awtsu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608566/basic-how-to-include-double-quotes-in-string/45608613#45608613) is correct for the normal BASIC language. (+1 for him)

However it didn't work for me on the PLC I've mentioned in the question.

Using `CHR$(&H22)` did the job for me. (also works on normal BASIC)

```
Print "Hello "+ CHR$(&H22) +"World"+CHR$(&H22)
```

It prints:

> Hello "World"

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
"She said, ""You deserve a treat!"" "
```

add "" ""

Comment: I tried this but its still not working. I'm trying to do this on nano10 PLC: www.triplc.com/nano10.htm

Comment: i update my answer kindly check if any of those works 
Thank you

Comment: can you post it in `this`

Answer (score 0):

Dushyant Bangal is correct - although CHR$(34) should work equally well. There is no need to put the value into hex unless you have a preference for it.

(Also, whether doubling up the "" works in "normal BASIC" depends what you mean by "normal".  I've seen countless dialects in which CHR$ is the only option.)

Comment: I tried `""`on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_freebasic_online.php and it worked, so figured it only doesn't work on this PLC. Good to know thats not the only one.