# VBA NumberFormat Implementation

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting

`NumberFormat` seems to be a straightforward function but I can't get it to work is a rather simple case. In the code below VBA tells me "Type Mismatch".

```
For j = 1 To last_column + 1
    For f = 2 To total_tranches + 1
        If allocation(f - 1, j - 1) = Empty And j <> 1 Then
            Allo1.Cells(AlShares.Row - 1 + f, j + 1) = 0
        Else
            Allo1.Cells(AlShares.Row - 1 + f, j + 1) = allocation(f - 1, j - 1)
            If j = 1 Then Allo1.Cells(AlShares.Row - 1 + f, j + 1).IndentLevel = 1
            If j = 2 Then Allo1.Cells(AlShares.Row - 1 + f, j + 1).NumberFormat = "_($*#,##0_);_($*(#,##0);_($*" - "??_);_(@_)"
        End If
    Next f
Next j
```

And if I replace specific formatting with "Accounting" it just does not work. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape double quote in VB string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4835691/11683)

Answer (score 2):

You are asking VBA to subtract 2 strings "...($*" - "??_.." so that is the type mismatch.

Comment: Interesting way of describing the problem.

Comment: Thank you it worked, and my other problems went away as another part of the code was overwriting your good formatting method!!